# How to read a BERT attention weight matrix?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, attention-model, self-attention, multihead-attention

I have extracted from the **last layer** and the **last attention head** of my **BERT** model the **attention score/weights matrix**. However I am not too sure how to read them. The matrix is the following one. I tried to find some more information in the literature but it was not successful. Any insights? Since the matrix is not symmetric and each rows sums to 1, I am confused. Thanks a lot !

[image]

```
  tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('Rostlab/prot_bert')
  inputs = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors='pt') 
  attention_mask=inputs['attention_mask']
  outputs = model(inputs['input_ids'],attention_mask) #len 30 as the model layers #outpus.attentions
  attention = outputs[-1]
attention = attention[-1] #last layer attention
layer_attention = layer_attention[-1] #last head attention
#... code to read it as a matrix with token labels
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attention matrix is asymmetric because `query` and `key` matrices differ.

At its core (leaving normalization constants and the multi-head trick aside) *(dot-product) self-attention* is computed as follows:

1. **Compute *key-query affinities*** (`e_ij`): given [image] (`T` being the sequence length, `q_i` and `k_j` being query and key vectors)

   [image]
2. **Compute *attention weights* from affinities** (`alpha_ij`):

   [image]

As you can see, you get the normalization of the affinities by summing over all keys given a query; said differently, in the denominator you're summing affinities by row (thus, probabilities sum to 1 over rows).

The way you should read the attention matrix is the following: *row tokens* (queries) attend to *column tokens* (keys) and the matrix weights represent a way to probabilistically measure where *attention* is directed to when querying over keys (i.e. to which key - and so to which token of the sentence - each query (token) mainly focuses to). Such interaction is *unidirectional* (you might look at each query as looking for information somewhere in the keys, the opposite interaction being irrelevant). I found the interpretation of the attention matrix as a *directed graph* within this [blogpost](https://theaisummer.com/self-attention/#:%7E:text=Self%2Dattention%20is%20not%20symmetric!&text=The%20arrows%20that%20correspond%20to,Q%E2%80%8B%3DWK%E2%80%8B.) very effective.

Eventually, I'd also suggest the first [BertViz medium post](https://towardsdatascience.com/deconstructing-bert-distilling-6-patterns-from-100-million-parameters-b49113672f77) which distinguishes different attention patterns and according to which your example would fall in the case where attention is mostly directed to the delimiter token [CLS].